# Angular 5 OAuth Authentication error - "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: angular, rest, http, oauth

I have a C# REST Api which works fine when using Postman for OAuth authentication with the same values, however using Angular I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" from the console.  What am I missing?

```
loginUser(username: string, password: string) {
    const bodyData = {
      grant_type: 'password',
      username: username,
      password: password,
      myCustomData: 'Hi There'
    };
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    Object.keys(bodyData).forEach(key => urlSearchParams.append(key, bodyData[key]));

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode;charset=UTF-8' );
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:19483/api/token', urlSearchParams, options)
      .map(response => {
        const retVal = response.json();
          return {
            'access_token': retVal.access_token,
            '.expires': retVal['.expires'],
            'userId': retVal.userId,
            'roles': retVal.roles
        };
      })
      .do(res => {
        if (res) {
          window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.access_token);
          window.localStorage.setItem('roles', res.roles);
          return res;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return Observable.of(false);
      });
  }
```

Comment: if you're using httpClient you have NOT use response.json()